# How to write a MYSQL CASE WHEN statement with multiple search conditions?

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures, case

I know languages like PHP has switch case control structure that supports multiple validations in a single case statement like,

```
Switch $x {
  case 1,2,3: 
      $a = 0;
       break;
  case 5,6: 
       $a = 1;
       break;
}
```

Similarly can this be done in MYSQL? I tried below, which really didn't work though :(

```
CASE vc_shape
   WHEN ('02' OR '51') THEN SET dc_square_1 = dc_square_1 + dc_row_total;
   WHEN ('06' OR  '30' OR 83) THEN SET dc_square_2 = dc_square_2 + dc_row_total; 
   .....
   .....
  ELSE
      BEGIN
      END;
END CASE;
```

Any ideas how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use the other format for `CASE` statements:

```
CASE 
   WHEN vc_shape IN ('02', '51') THEN SET dc_square_1 = dc_square_1 + dc_row_total;
   WHEN vc_shape IN ('06', '30', '83') THEN SET dc_square_2 = dc_square_2 + dc_row_total; 
   .....
   .....
  ELSE
      BEGIN
      END;
END CASE;
```