# Multiple When case inside a join in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, case-when

I currently have a problem with the multiple **when** into **case**. When I remove the second **when**, it works. What is wrong with it?

The reported MYSQL error is:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'as param2 on param2.param_micro_site=i1.i_micro_site else null END )' at line 1
```

I tried these suggestions:

[MySQL - Combining multiple WHEN conditions in CASE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18991091/mysql-combining-multiple-when-conditions-in-case)

[How to write a MYSQL CASE WHEN statement with multiple search conditions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12523630/how-to-write-a-mysql-case-when-statement-with-multiple-search-conditions)

But it didn't solved my problem.

```
SELECT * FROM items i1
join param on 
(
case 
    when (ITEM_ID=param_item_id and i_status=1 and item_page=164) 
    then param_item_id=ITEM_ID 
    when (i_micro_site>=1 and i_status=7 and (EXISTS(select * from multiple where multiple_id=ITEM_ID and multiple_cat=21 and multiple_enum="item") || item_page=169)) 
    then (SELECT * from items i2 join pages on i2.item_page=p_ID and p_cat in (21,29,0) join param where param_micro_site=i1.i_micro_site and param_item_id in(i1.ITEM_ID,i2.ITEM_ID)) as param2 on param2.param_micro_site=i1.i_micro_site 
else null END 
)
```

Thank you

Comment: You should edit the question an include the error message.

Comment: the closing parenthesis in your second then should be before else `(SELECT * from items i2 join pages on i2.item_page=p_ID and p_cat in (21,29,0) join param where param_micro_site=i1.i_micro_site and param_item_id in(i1.ITEM_ID,i2.ITEM_ID) as param2 on param2.param_micro_site=i1.i_micro_site)`, but even then seems your expression in the second then more than suspect. It should return one column with one row to qualify for a join condition.

Comment: This looks extremely unlikely to perform well, as you're probably going to RBAR (row-by-agonizing-row) your join - no use of indices, executing another query each row.... You'd be better off figuring out another way to write this.

Comment: Thank you for your Answers, but for the moment I still didn't resolved it. Clockwork-Muse, you are probably right. But I can't figure it out. The idea is to go threw all the param of the item itself or it's parents if this item is a child (why I used the `when`). The parents are represented with p_cat of `(21,29,0)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is an attempt to format your query in a somewhat readable way:

```
SELECT *
FROM items i1 join
     param
     on (case when (ITEM_ID=param_item_id and i_status=1 and item_page=164) 
              then param_item_id=ITEM_ID 
              when (i_micro_site>=1 and i_status=7 and
                    (EXISTS(select *
                            from multiple
                            where multiple_id=ITEM_ID and multiple_cat=21 and multiple_enum="item"
                           ) || item_page=169
                    )
                   ) 
              then (SELECT *
                    from items i2 join
                         pages on i2.item_page=p_ID and p_cat in (21,29,0) join
                         param
                    where param_micro_site=i1.i_micro_site and
                          param_item_id in(i1.ITEM_ID,i2.ITEM_ID)
                   ) as param2
on param2.param_micro_site=i1.i_micro_site 
else null END 
)
```

Here are observations up to the `on` after `param2`:

- The subquery for the `then` clause is finished.
- A subquery in a `then` clause cannot take a column (or table) alias.
- The subquery is returning more than one column.  Even if all tables in the subquery had only one column, the `*` would bring back more than one.

Apart from the syntax, this query is just entirely unreadable.  I would suggest that you ask another question, provide table layouts, sample data, and desired results.  Someone can probably figure out a better way to write the query that you have attempted.

Comment: Gordon, thank you for this answer. I finally used this line of code `then param_item_id = (SELECT param_item_id from items i2 join pages on i2.item_page=p_ID and p_cat in (21,29,0) join param as param1 where param_micro_site=i1.i_micro_site and param_item_id=i2.ITEM_ID  order by p_cat limit 1)
` instead and it worked. I though it would have not pass thru because of the missing `*` and the use of `param_micro_site` in where clause